# Running current into a guitar pickup

Tags: audio, electromagnetism, oscillation, instrumentation

When a guitar string oscillates over a magnetic-coil guitar pickup, the pickup produces an alternating current.

Would it be possible to do the reverse of this, and feed an alternating current into a pickup to manually oscillate the string? If so, would the signal type being fed into the pickup, have to be the same as the signal typically output by the pickup? (except higher amplitude)

My intentions were to create a sort of "e-bow" style pickup fitted into the guitar, that's only purpose was to excite the strings, with a frequency that I could control with a micro controller

([e-bow demonstration](http://youtu.be/4oSXlB2Q4us))

Comment: If the frequency of oscillation is normally determined by mechanically constraining the physical length of the string, then how do you propose to create frequencies other than those of open strings?

Comment: AIUI, the e-bow uses bidirectional coupling such that the mechanical resonance of the string does determine (or at least influence) the oscillator frequency.

Comment: FYI: The Fernandes sustainer is similar to what you're looking for: http://www.fernandesguitars.com/sustainer-kits.html

Comment: Pickups have moderately strong permanent magnets in them; this requires that they be some distance away from the strings to avoid having the magnets tug unduly on the strings.  It would probably be possible to use electromagnets to vibrate the strings, but you'd probably want to use an electromagnets with non-magnetized cores, and note that without the permanent magnet the electromagnet would attract the string when driven with either polarity, so the drive waveform would have to take that into account.

Comment: @DaveTweed That's interesting, I'm quite familiar with physics of sound (in the case of guitar, I'm experienced in string theory (HA)) but I'm a newbie in EE, and I can't seem to find anything online about bi-directional coupling, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible to do the reverse of this, and feed an alternating current into a pickup to manually oscillate the string?

Yes. If we were to think of guitar pickups in this way normally, we'd call them electromagnets. To the extent that you run a current through the pickup, it will attract the string magnetically.

> excite the strings, with a frequency that I could control with a micro controller

That might not work as you expect. To get a tone out of the strings, you need the strings to resonate with the frequency you are using to excite them. The string's resonant frequency is determined by its mass and length. Without your fingers to change the length of the string, you are limited to the pitch of open strings.

If you try to excite the strings at other frequencies, you might get a sound, but it probably won't sound like a natural guitar. Whatever sound you do get will be colored by the resonances of the strings. You might get some interesting effects at harmonic frequencies. At other frequencies it may just sound very dull and quiet, or not be audible at all.

Comment: What about the magnetics of the pickups, don't you think that a DC signal (just speculating) can modify their magnetic characteristic?

Comment: It's possible that you could use *two* pickups, one to drive the string and the other for feedback.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento sure, it will modify their characteristic in some way. Not sure if it would be a *useful* way. It might just make them warm.

Comment: How about the magnitude of the motion vs current in the coil?  Just because you can amplify the coil signal enough to make use of it, doesn't mean that passing current through it can produce enough force to move the string.

Comment: @ScottSeidman at resonance it takes very little force to move the string, since the energy of each oscillation adds to the previous, the only losses being the mechanical damping of the string, which is very low by design. I haven't tried it, but intuition tells me the pickup can provide sufficient force to excite the string at resonance.

Comment: Well, a long time ago I was making a guitar effect stompbox, and put DC into the pickup for a time, I think I lose my pickups by their future sound. I checked caps, potentiometers, and the pickups DC impedance and all seems good. Anyway, remember that the string to pickup have different distances, so it can work on one and not in the other, and that the signal may need a delay (or phase change) so that it will act adding to the oscillation not stopping it.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento ok, so don't put DC into the pickups. I'm sure if you do it too much, the pickups can overheat, which might melt plastic, heat magnetic materials past their Curie temperature, or otherwise break stuff. The proposal here is to apply AC, not DC.

Comment: @PhilFrost that has just a curiosity. Anyway I think I have put 12V (I don't remember the coil impedance so I don't know the current) but it don't ever get a smell of insulation overheating. I doubt then that it can anywhere near 200°C that is lower than the curie temperature for most materials.

Comment: Thankyou for this answer. I was too vague about the part with the micro-controller, I was wanting to sample the output of one pickup, work out a harmonic of what was being played, and then feed it back into the string with my other pickup. I'll accept this answer as it answered my yes/no question